# Action Listener is not working when I press a Button

Tags: java, swing, jframe, actionlistener

I got this code but when I run it the `actionListener` is not working.

**Code**

```
public class MenuPrincipal extends javax.swing.JFrame implements ActionListener {

public MenuPrincipal() {
    initComponents();
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.addListener();
    this.jButton1 = new JButton();
    this.jButton2 = new JButton();
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    new MenuPrincipal();
}

private void addListener() {   
    this.jButton1.addActionListener(this);
    this.jButton2.addActionListener(this);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Activado");
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    if(event.getSource().equals(this.JButton1){
        // do something
    }

    if(event.getSource().equals(this.JButton2){
        // do something
    }
}

}
```

I'm using Netbeans to make the interface, thus I'm not pasting here the generated code.

Comment: You are doing nothing in `actionPerformed`?

Comment: You don't implement `ActionListener` interface, also `actionPerformed` method body is empty.

Comment: yes yes inside the If statement is like a JOptionPane to see if its working but the buttons doesn't work

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you.

Comment: MenuPrincipal constructor, you call addListerner first and then create jbuttons. technically this should throw a NullpointerException. if it is not you have already created jbuttons and placed them in the GUI and add addListerners to them and then assign new instance references to jbutton1 and 2 and use them in the actionPerformed. so event.getSource().equals(this.JButton2) will never be true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write something in the method of the handler:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
   System.out.println("button pressed!");
}
```

and your class should implement the ActionListener interface

Alternatively you can use the java8 lambdas:

```
btn.addActionListener(e -> {System.out.println("button pressed!)});
```

Comment: sorry I forgot to put something in there now its complete

Comment: Do you know about lambdas?

Comment: No sir I don't, should I search for it ?

Comment: See my updated answer: Instead of writing your own ActionListener you can just use a lambda expression. That is not easy to explain. It works for interfaces with a single method, also called functional interfaces. Please try it.

Comment: You are welcome! Please accept my answer, if it solves your problem and enjoy your journey to production!

Answer (score 0):

remove this 2 lines from the constructor

```
this.jButton1 = new JButton();
this.jButton2 = new JButton();
```

Since addLsiteners method didnt throw any exception, that means you have already instantiated those JButtons. if you re instantiated then those fields will have the reference to different instances than the instance you added the action listener .